# Azure SQL server accees from VBA Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, azure

first I want to say that, I'm very new with Azure and Sql server.

second, I have an Excel VBA code that create select query from an Azure SQL SERVER db.

On my local PC it works fine but when I'm trying to use the VBA code from another computer I get the attached error.

Is it something to do with security maybe ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2eZH.png)

Comment: Different computer, different IP address? If so, whitelist that IP to the server firewall

Comment: You need to alter the SQL Firewall in Azure to accept connections from the new computers IP Address. Someone must have already done this for your computer

Comment: .... or the new PC's has an outgoing firewall restriction on 1433

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Database service creates a firewall at the database server level for single and pooled databases. This firewall prevents client applications from connecting to the server or any of its single or pooled databases unless you create an IP firewall rule to open the firewall. For a connection from an IP address outside Azure, create a firewall rule for a specific IP address or range of addresses that you want to be able to connect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule